# buildBeanDefinition failing with Spring Statemachine Framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-statemachine

I'm trying to utilize the Spring Statemachine framework in my project, however I'm encountering a building bean definition error at compile-time.

```
2017-07-25 16:37:25.462:WARN:oejd.DeploymentManager:Scanner-1: Unable to reach node goal: started
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.RootBeanDefinition.setTargetType(Lorg/springframework/core/ResolvableType;)V
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.configuration.StateMachineConfiguration.buildBeanDefinition(StateMachineConfiguration.java:109)
    at org.springframework.statemachine.config.common.annotation.AbstractImportingAnnotationConfiguration.registerBeanDefinitions(AbstractImportingAnnotationConfiguration.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:444)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:326)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
```

I'm following along with [step 7](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-config)  in my Spring MVC application. I am not using SpringBoot, but I don't think I'm missing any sub-files.

Here is my code for the StateMachineConfig file:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnableStateMachine;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineStateConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.config.builders.StateMachineTransitionConfigurer;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListener;
import org.springframework.statemachine.listener.StateMachineListenerAdapter;
import org.springframework.statemachine.state.State;

import java.util.EnumSet;


@Configuration
@EnableStateMachine
public class StateMachineConfig
        extends EnumStateMachineConfigurerAdapter<States, Events> {

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineConfigurationConfigurer<States, Events> config)
            throws Exception {
        config
                .withConfiguration()
                .autoStartup(true)
                .listener(listener());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineStateConfigurer<States, Events> states)
            throws Exception {
        states
                .withStates()
                .initial(States.SI)
                .states(EnumSet.allOf(States.class));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(StateMachineTransitionConfigurer<States, Events> transitions)
            throws Exception {
        transitions
                .withExternal()
                .source(States.SI).target(States.S1).event(Events.E1)
                .and()
                .withExternal()
                .source(States.S1).target(States.S2).event(Events.E2);
    }

    @Bean
    public StateMachineListener<States, Events> listener() {
        return new StateMachineListenerAdapter<States, Events>() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(State<States, Events> from, State<States, Events> to) {
                System.out.println("State change to " + to.getId());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is the controller that I am attempting to use the StateMachine in (Note: I removed the @Autowired tag above the instantiation of the stateMachine as intelliJ kept saying "No beans of 'StateMachine' type found". This may be the culprit of my problems?):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HomeController {

    private StateMachine<States, Events> stateMachine;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
            stateMachine.sendEvent(Events.E1);
            return "redirect:/target/list";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NoSuchMethodError` if points to spring core classes mean that there is a mixup of framework versions. You are probably letting statemachine pom to resolve some versions and your own build adds something else.

Your maven or gradle build file probably shows why core framework jars have different versions. If using boot then you'd pretty much get correct versions, without it you need to manage versions manually.

Comment: That makes sense. Is there a way to know which jar versions I need to use with statemachine? My project was compiling and running earlier, and I've only merely added the above code to the existing code base, as well as the spring-statemachine-core dependency in the POM file.

Comment: Thank you, this helped. I upgraded my existing POM versions for some of the core spring frameworks from 3.2.5.RELEASE to 4.2.3.RELEASE.